# Is it possible to do a non-blocking read of MyISAM table?

Tags: mysql, concurrency, nonblocking, myisam

I have a log table with heavy write operations: that was the reason of choosing MyISAM for it.

Now I need to execute a complicated SELECT query which takes a lot time and blocks the table: no one can write to it then.

- The table has a high 'write' load
- I don't care if I don't get the most recent records
- The data is never deleted

What are the options to read the data without blocking the table?

- LIMIT is applied after the query is completed, so is not an option
- Modifying all INSERT statements to make them DELAYED is not an option
- InnoDB is also is not an option
- HANDLER query is not an option: I need complex WHERE conditions

Comment: Out of curiosity, why is InnoDB not an option?

Comment: Mostly because of the heavy writing. And also - historically :)

Comment: But InnoDB isn't slower than MyISAM.. Would TokuDB be an option maybe?

Comment: You have set 4 limitations. Could you at least post the query and the table definition (including indexes)? Otherwise this question reads as "I have a problem but I can't tell you any details, give me advice"

Comment: @ypercube, table definition has nothing to do with the question: it's a generic approach, not a specific task :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some suggestions, maybe one or the other is suitable for you

1. option: Slave

   Configure a slave that you use for your SELECT query. That won't block the inserts.
   However, this requires a second server, some configuration and storage space, so this is not a good solution, just to get your data.
2. option: use low-priority-updates: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/table-locking.html

   This can be done on a server level or connection level, so you don't have to modify every insert statement.
3. worker process

   - Make your inserts as usual.
   - create a worker process that "moves" your log entries (for each row in table A, make a insert in table B, delete row in Table A) to another table.
   - Now you can query Table B